# Is there a way to share an APFS partition on Linux?

Tags: linux, samba, apfs

I want to share over the network a partition formatted as APFS using my laptop with Ubuntu 20. I was wondering if there is a way to share the partition "raw" so I can connect to it from my Mac as Linux doesn't support APFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to set up macOS as an iSCSI initiator and Linux as an iSCSI target. However, this seems to require third-party kexts on the macOS side and might not be supported in the future.

Linux has a few APFS drivers available (apfs-fuse and Paragon APFS).

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it isn't that easy. I'm aware of Paragon APFS which allows write access, but they don't offer a trial version. I ended up changing file systems around and is working fine now. Thanks for your help.